# Git folding commits without squash

Tags: git, version-control, squash

I have the following scenario:

I have some staged changes and I have 3 commits ahead of master. I want the staged changes to be apart of the oldest commit of the three. There are a couple ways I know of to do this, but I'm looking for alternate/better methods. Here's the first method that I could think of.

```
git commit -m "Some dummy message since its going to get squashed"
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

Which will bring up an editor, and I can move the dummy commit where I want it and then squash it.

Is there a better/faster/or just different way to do this? I'm really just trying to be more productive, and learn git inside and out, so any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use git reset, as described here: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/PackardChan/git-scm.com/blob/blog-revive/app/views/blog/posts/2011-07-11-reset.html

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

then simply

```
git commit
```

again.